Kafka's fetch.max.bytes and max.partition.fetch.bytes do not work
According to documentation, fetch.max.bytes and max.partition.fetch.bytes should limit the maximum size of a message consumed by Kafka client.
I set "max.poll.records" to "1" because documentation states that first batch is not limited in size. I set "fetch.max.bytes" and "max.partition.fetch.bytes" to "1". I use default broker and topic properties.
When large messages are produced, they are successfully consumed despite the documentation. I assume that if a message is out of size, the broker should throw an exception or such message should be omitted. Instead of this consumer receives and processes large messages.
If this is an expected behavior, then in what cases are messages filtered?
I have tried to run the following code.
package io.conduktor.demos.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConsumerDemo {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerDemo.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("I am a Kafka Consumer");

        String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";
        String groupId = "my-fifth-application";
        String topic = "demo_java";

        // create consumer configs
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "1"); 
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "1");

        // create consumer
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

        try {
            // subscribe consumer to our topic(s)
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));

            // poll for new data
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records =
                        consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));

                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    log.info("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value: " + record.value());
                    log.info("Partition: " + record.partition() + ", Offset:" + record.offset());
                }
            }

        } catch (WakeupException e) {
            log.info("Wake up exception!");
            // we ignore this as this is an expected exception when closing a consumer
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unexpected exception", e);
        } finally {
            consumer.close(); // this will also commit the offsets if need be.
            log.info("The consumer is now gracefully closed.");
        }

    }
}

And send a big message with kafka-console-producer.

This is the expected behavior. The documentation of fetch.max.bytes and max.partition.fetch.bytes both state (emphasis mine):

Records are fetched in batches by the consumer, and if the first
record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger
than this value, the record batch will still be returned to ensure
that the consumer can make progress.


But it does not filter out messages, even if it is the second batch. In what cases does it filter a message?
